# How to install a storybook in a yarn-berry environment

Tags: storybook, yarn-berry

I'm going to install a storybook in a yarn-berry environment.
When I install the storybook using the `yarn dlx -p @storybook/cli sb init` command, The node_modules folder is created.

What seems to be the problem?